# How can I merge two SubVersion branches to one working copy without committing?

Tags: version-control, svn

My current SubVersion workflow is like so:

1. The trunk is used to make small content changes and bug fixes to the main source code.
2. Branches are used for adding/editing enhancements and projects.

So, trunk changes are made, tested, committed and deployed pretty quickly. Whereas, enhancements and projects need additional user testing and approval.

At time, I have two branches that need testing and approval at the same time. I don't want to merge to the trunk and commit until the changes are fully tested and approved.

What I need to do is merge both branches to one working copy without any commits.

I am using Tortoise SVN, and when I try to merge the second branch, I get an error message:

> **Cannot merge into a working copy that has local modifications**

Is there a way that I can do this without committing either merge?

Comment: Looks like the error message is being generated because you have changes not committed to the branch, nothing to do with the merge itself.

Comment: In a terminal, svn has a `--force` argument for exactly this.  Does Tortoise SVN not support it?

Comment: I decided to go bigger picture here and completely rethink our testing/deployment procedure to prevent issues like this.

Answer (score 2):

You currently have the trunk and 2 branches A and B (which are both branches from the trunk).  I suggest you create yet another branch called AB as follows:

1. Switch your working folder to the trunk, if not there already
2. Update the latest and make sure you have no local modifications.  If you do, either commit them (to the trunk) or revert them as appropriate.
3. Do one last update of your working folder from the trunk.  Note the revision number you have updated to (call it revision R).
4. In the repo, copy revision R of the trunk to a new branch called "AB" (Do **not** switch your working folder to AB yet)
5. Merge your working folder with A.
6. Switch your working folder to AB.
7. Commit your working folder (to AB) and update (from AB).
8. Switch your working folder to the trunk.
9. Merge your working folder with B.
10. Switch your working folder to AB.
11. Commit your working folder to AB.
12. Test, and commit any fixes to AB.
13. When it's working and you're ready to merge everything to the trunk, do a final commit (to AB), then update your working folder (from AB).
14. Switch your working folder to the trunk.
15. Merge your working folder with AB
16. Test and fix
17. When it's working, commit working folder to the trunk.
18. Go out for beers

Answer (score 1):

Every merge operation is done in your local sandbox. You do not have to be worried until you commit some junky code.

I don't know the whole deploy process you do but what you can do is:

1. switch to branch A
2. merge branch A with branch B
3. build the app, deploy and test it

If all works fine you can commit all changes (you are on branch A). Then you can switch to trunk and merge with branch A. After all conflicts are solved you can commit on trunk and that is all.

Comment: I don't think that will work... you can't "merge branch A with branch B" because B is not a branch of A... rather B is a branch of the the trunk

Comment: This does not work because I may want to only deploy one change at a time.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar workflow at one point. The solution I finally landed on was to keep multiple local copies, basically one per branch. Got a bit dicey at times with shared databases but overall it was very successful.

Answer (score 1):

you can checkout another copy of the branch you want to merge into at a different place on your local drive, merge into it and then commit it. Then delete the whole 2nd working copy and return to your current task.

But it does seem that you are trying to subvert your own working practices - unless you want to just merge 2 branches together to commit all the work simultaneously and delete the 2 old branches... but then, what's stopping you from committing to them and merging normally in such a case?

Answer (score 1):

Eric, " I may want to only deploy one change at a time..." and "merge two  branches to one working copy without committing" are incompatible requirements: or you'll test branch after branch or mix two branches in one big mix.

**Version A** Anyway - you can **merge any node with any node** inside repo-tree, not only *somebranch* with trunk. I.e., in common, @JoelFan workflow is good, but - require less actions

1. copy HEAD of trunk to AB
2. Merge AB with A
3. Commit mergeset, test etc...
4. Merge AB with B
5. Test merged results
6. Merge to trunk and delete temporary AB-branch

**Version B** is 2-URL merge. `svn help merge`, "2-URL Merge Example" part as start. You can merge 2 independent branches into third in one command `merge BRANCHA[@N] BRANCHB[@M] [TRUNK_WCPATH]`

Comment: what I'm saying is, I may want to test both branches simultaneously to make sure they are compatible, but without committing them, as they be compatible, but I only want to deploy one this week, and the other two weeks from now.

Comment: @EricBelair - checkout (2) additional WC of trunk, merge branchA in WC1, branchB in WC2 ?!